# Why does beforeUpdate runs before onMount?

Tags: svelte

Quoting the tutorial :

> Note that beforeUpdate will first run before the component has mounted, so we need to check for the existence of div before reading its properties.

The way I think about the lifecycle is that a component is first *mounted* and after it is *updated*

Just why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is only fully mounted *after* the first update, so logically `beforeUpdate` happens before that. Regarding terminology, you can see the mounting of the component as *updating* the DOM.

In the end it is primarily a design decision, whether you include/exclude the initial "update". For me this makes sense and keeps things simple/consistent (no need for additional functions).

Comment: I am not facing any issues. This was genuinely a  theoretical question. The way I was thinking about it was the component is first *mounted* and then it is *updated*. I updated my question to clarify that. IIUC you are saying that mounting the component counts as an update, which is strange to me.

Comment: It's just a design decision whether to count it or not. You could see it as an update from no state to initial state.

Comment: Also, it updates the existing DOM/rest of the page.

Comment: Oh right, it is indeed more intuitive to think about i as beforeDomUpdate. You say that there's no need for additional function but actually, beforeUpdate oftentimes forces a check on your part to see if some DOM element exists. A bit like reactive statement that run at the end of initiliazation although you probably want them to run on first change. So I personally see it as a corner case that needs handling.

Comment: As I originally stated, though, you should rarely ever need `beforeUpdate` in the first place. What I meant is that Svelte does not need to define additional lifecycle functions, the distinction can be done in user code. I also very rarely use `onMount`, if you want to access DOM when it is created the most straightforward method is using [actions](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action), I used to forget that they exists but they are often just better. They also do not require any imports.

Comment: You proved your point as I had already forgot about actions and relied a lot on onMount where it could have been avoided with actions.